# PHP extract elements from an array which have a common name

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'd like to extract only up to a certain part of the name and test if it's set (isset)?

Specifically for largeImage_**1**, largeImage_**2**, etc..

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't seem to return or test.

```
if ($_POST['tutorial']) {

  foreach ( $_POST['tutorial'] as $key => $value ) {

    if ('largeImage' === substr($key, 0 , 10) )
      {
           echo $value;
      }

  }

} 

Array
(
[title] => title
[tutorial] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [largeImage_1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => image.png
                        [1] => image.png
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [largeImage_2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => image.png
                    )

            )

    )

[name] => ""; 

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop within another loop to access keys like 'largeImage_1', 'largeImage_2'.

```
if ($_POST['tutorial']) {
  foreach ( $_POST['tutorial'] as $key => $value ) {
        foreach ( $value as $k => $v ) {
            if ('largeImage' === substr($k, 0 , 10) )
            {
                //your code here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome, thanks!  How can I test to see if it's isset or in my POSTED array?

Comment: Use array_key_exists function to check whether keys like 'largeImage_1', 'largeImage_2' etc exist or not.

Comment: How do I return the values of the array?  When I try echo $v, I get "array"  Obviously I want to return, image.png..   Thank you!

Comment: Use another foreach loop within the second loop to get the value image.png.